# how to increase the page loading speed of particular page

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress site havng one of the page http://inspire.mobi/shop using "printfection" plugin for "t-shirts" shop. But page is taking too much time to load as compared to other pages even other sites using printfection.  How i will increase the speed of page loading?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing your current URL with Google Page Speed Insights @ https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fchange.is_2Fshop_3Fshopctg_3Deverything&mobile=false

I would suggest that you first serve proper sized images, as currently many of your images should be resized in HTML or CSS from 380x380 to 266x266.

Secondly, I would get a caching plugin, either W3TC or WP Super Cache.

Thirdly, I would install WP Smushit and run it to losslessly compress your existing images.